# Kahn's algorithms to arrange CouseSchedule

Tags: python, performance, algorithm, programming-challenge, graph

I wrote a solution to [Course Schedule II - LeetCode](https://leetcode.com/problems/course-schedule-ii/)

> There are a total of *n* courses you have to take, labeled from `0` to `n-1`.
>
> Some courses may have prerequisites, for example to take course 0 you have to first take course 1, which is expressed as a pair: `[0,1]`
>
> Given the total number of courses and a list of prerequisite **pairs**, return the ordering of courses you should take to finish all courses.
>
> There may be multiple correct orders, you just need to return one of them. If it is impossible to finish all courses, return an empty array.
>
> **Example 1:**
>
> ```
> Input: 2, [[1,0]] 
> Output: [0,1]
> Explanation: There are a total of 2 courses to take. To take course 1 you should have finished
> ```
>
> **Example 2:**
>
> ```py
> Input: 4, [[1,0],[2,0],[3,1],[3,2]]
> Output: [0,1,2,3] or [0,2,1,3]
> Explanation: 
> There are a total of 4 courses to take. To take course 3 you should have finished both     
>  courses 1 and 2. Both courses 1 and 2 should be taken after you finished course 0. 
>   So one correct course order is [0,1,2,3]. Another correct ordering is [0,2,1,3] .
> ```
>
> **Note:**
>
> 1. The input prerequisites is a graph represented by **a list of edges**, not adjacency matrices. Read more about [how a graph is represented](https://www.khanacademy.org/computing/computer-science/algorithms/graph-representation/a/representing-graphs).
> 2. You may assume that there are no duplicate edges in the input prerequisites.

my solution

```
class Solution:
    def findOrder(self,numCourses, prerequirements):
        """
        :type numCourse: int
        :type prerequirements: List[List[int]]
        :rtype:bool
        """
        #if not prerequirements: return True 
       # if numCourses == None and len(prerequirements) == 0: return True

        L = []

        in_degrees = [ 0 for _ in range(numCourses)] #index as node
        #graph = [[]] * numCourses
        graph = [[] for _ in range(numCourses)]

        #Construct the graph 
        for u, v in prerequirements:
            graph[v].append(u) #index as node
            in_degrees[u] += 1 
        logging.debug(f"graph: {graph}")
        logging.debug(f"in_degrees {in_degrees}")
        #
        Q = [i for i in range(len(in_degrees)) if in_degrees[i]==0] #collect nodes without pre-edges
        logging.debug(f"Q: {Q}")

        while Q: #while Q is not empty 
            start = Q.pop()#remove a node from Q
            L.append(start) #add n to tail of L
            logging.debug(f"L: {L}")

            for v in graph[start]:#for each node v with a edge e 
                in_degrees[v] -= 1 #remove edge 
                if in_degrees[v] == 0:
                    Q.append(v)
        logging.debug(f"indegree: {in_degrees}")
        #check there exist a cycle
        for i in range(len(in_degrees)): #if graph has edge 
            if in_degrees[i] > 0: 
                return [] 
        logging.debug(f"L: {L}")
        return L
```

TestCase:

```
class MyCase(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.solution1 = Solution()
        self.solution2 = Solution2()

    def test_bfs1(self):
        numCourse = 2
        prerequirements =  [[1,0]] 
        check = self.solution1.findOrder(numCourse, prerequirements)
        logging.debug(f"{check}")
        answer = [0, 1] 
        self.assertEqual(check, answer)


    def test_bfs2(self):
        numCourse = 4
        prerequirements =  [[1,0],[2,0],[3,1],[3,2]]
        check = self.solution1.findOrder(numCourse, prerequirements)
        logging.debug(f"{check}")
        answer = [[0,1,2,3], [0,2,1,3]] 
        self.assertIn(check, answer)


    def test_bfs3(self):
        numCourse = 2
        prerequirements =  []
        check = self.solution1.findOrder(numCourse, prerequirements)
        logging.debug(f"{check}")
        answer = [1,0]
        self.assertEqual(check, answer)


    def test_bfs4(self):
        numCourse = 2
        prerequirements =  [[0,1],[1,0]]
        check = self.solution1.findOrder(numCourse, prerequirements)
        logging.debug(f"{check}")
        answer = []
        self.assertEqual(check, answer)
```

Get a low score

> Runtime: 56 ms, faster than 57.28% of Python3 online submissions for Course Schedule II.
>   Memory Usage: 14 MB, less than 51.41% of Python3 online submissions for Course Schedule II.

Comment: Your code uses less time and less memory than a half of all submissions in the same language. It's certainly not a _low score_.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- The docstring is wrong. `findOrder` returns a list, not a boolean.
- Few inefficiencies:

  - The cycle checking implementation is way suboptimal. The algorithm terminates successfully if *every* node lands in `L`. It is enough to test that `len(L) = len(in_degrees)`. No need to loop.
  - You don't need `Q`. You may work directly with `L`. Less memory, and less copying. Admittedly, the resulting code may look a bit scary (list is modified while being iterated on), but `append` appears to be safe. You may find [this discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48604036/3403834) interesting.
- `[i for i in range(len(in_degrees)) if in_degrees[i]==0]` doesn't look Pythonic. Consider

  ```
      [i for i, n in enumerate(in_degrees) if n == 0]
  ```
- To my taste, the code is commented too much.

<strike>- Nitpick. Strictly speaking, the problem statement doesn't guarantee that the courses IDs are dense. A schedule may look like `3, [[100, 200], [200, 300]]`. In such case case `graph[v].append(u)` will raise an `IndexError`. Consider a dictionary instead of a list as a graph representation.</strike>

Comment: Strictly speaking, the problem statement _does_ guarantee it: _**There are a total of n courses you have to take, labeled from `0` to `n-1`.**_ However, it does not specify the possible range for _n_; specifically, it doesn't guarantee _n_ will fit in the standard `int` type.

Comment: @CiaPan Thanks. Misread the PS. Edited.